# Windows Azure: Combining Azure Tables with SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have some structured tables to handle connections between users. I have managed to get this to work in Google App Engine(Like Azure Tables). I am considering moving to Azure and combining Tables with SQL.

Scenario:

**Step 1:**

SQL: Find user relations in **Azure SQL Database**, user A and user B is connected.

**Step 2:**

Search **Azure Tables** with user A id and user B id. Each user is uploading images and other unstructured posts.

I guess this is a well known scenario, I am just looking to combine the two for best:

- Performance
- Scalability
- Pricing

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to move the data from SQL Azure to Azure Table Storage by combining relevant data?

Comment: No, I was thinking about using the relational sql database for user relations and then save big data(many posts and images) to Azure Tables.

Comment: I see. Instead of saving the big data into Azure Tables, I would recommend saving the data in Azure Blob Storage because in tables, each attribute (equivalent to column) can be of a maximum of 64 KB in size and each entity (equivalent to row) can be of a maximum of 1 MB in size. So you store these big items in blob storage and store the URL of the blob in your SQL table along with the data.

Comment: Gaurav, great input. It is the same on Google App Engine. But what about sharding and scaling rows in Azure SQL Database? Now I am thinking to combine Azure Sql Database, Azure Tables and Blob Service. Thanks for you input.